# How to do multiple "echo $count" at the end of while read loop?

Tags: bash

I used a while read loop in shell script to count the number of lines between 12:00:00 and 18:00:00 of a file.txt and the script has worked very well. Now I want to extend this procedure to count lines number between following time steps:

```
00:00:00 and 05:59:59;
06:00:00 and 11:59:59;
12:00:00 and 17:59:59;
18:00:00 and 23:59:59;
```

See the first script followed by its results

```
  #!/bin/bash

  let count=0

  while read cdat ctim clat clon
       do
          h=${ctim:0:2};    # substring hours from ctim
          m=${ctim:3:2};
          s=${ctim:6:2};
           if [[ $h -ge 12 && $h -le 17 ]] || [[ $ctim == "18:00:00" ]]; then
             let count=$count+1
             echo $count $cdat $ctim $clat $clon          
           fi

       done  <  cloud.txt 
       echo $count
  exit
```

Results :

```
1 2014/11/21 16:05:00 19.56 -05.30
2 2014/01/31 13:55:00 02.00 31.10
3 2014/04/00 14:20:00 17.42 12.14
4 2014/07/25 15:30:00 35.25 05.90
5 2014/05/15 12:07:00 23.95 07.11
6 2014/07/29 17:34:00 44.00 17.43
7 2014/03/20 18:00:00 -11.12 -22.05
8 2014/09/21 12:00:00 06.44 41.55
8
```

I want to do the same thing getting different results according to the corresponding time step, but in the same script. I want to print out one by one the different results as above.

Answer (score 0):

I would edit your initial script to take the start and end times in as a parameter, and then write a second script that gives your first the time values you want (just a list of start and end times, and maybe an output file if you want the counts to be separate). You need to edit your first script to ignore everything up until the start time, and then just yank the 18:00:00 out and replace it with an endtime variable.

That way, you can easily run a report for whatever time period you want, and you already have the logic set up to calculate the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

```
count=()
total=0
while read cdat ctim rest; do
    if   [[ $ctim == "00:00:00" ]] || [[ "00:00:00" < $ctim && $ctim < "06:00:00" ]]; then
        index=0
    elif [[ $ctim == "06:00:00" ]] || [[ "06:00:00" < $ctim && $ctim < "12:00:00" ]]; then
        index=6
    elif [[ $ctim == "12:00:00" ]] || [[ "12:00:00" < $ctim && $ctim < "18:00:00" ]]; then
        index=12
    else
        index=18
    fi
    (( count[index]++ ))
    (( total ++ ))
    echo ${count[index]} $cdat $ctim $rest
done < file

for index in 0 6 12 18; do
    echo "count between $index and $((index+6)): ${count[index]}"
done
echo total count: $total
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Jackman, I think your suggested script can help me to achieve my work, even though I am still getting some errors, and I am not getting the individual lines number for each time step, but for global one. See the result: ./fileproc5.sh: line 6: [[: 00:00:00: syntax error in expression (error token is ":00:00")./fileproc5.sh: line 8: [[: 06:00:00: syntax error in expression (error token is ":00:00")
16 2014/04/06 04:53:00 36.11 07.21
count between 0 and 6: 
count between 6 and 12: 
count between 12 and 18: 
count between 18 and 24: 16
total count: 16
Can you you help me to improve it?

Comment: Ah, right. For string comparision, there's no `<=` operator. Only `==`, `<` and `>`. Updated

Comment: Hi. Thank you Mr. Jackman. Now there is no error. But now if I want to get separately the number of lines for each time step,how can I do it? For instance, number of lines between 0 and 6 =? 3 maybe and so on. Like I have total count = 16, but what about individual time steps {[0 -6], [6-12], [12-18]}? See my results: count between 0 and 6: 
count between 6 and 12: 
count between 12 and 18: 1
count between 18 and 24: 15
total count: 16

Comment: Change `${count[index]}` to `${count[index]-0}` in the echo command inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes, it works, but not expected number. See result: count between 0-6: 0
count between 6-12: 0
count between 12-18: 1
count between 18-24: 12
total count: 13
See data content: 
2014/04/00 10:44:05 26.12 -23.22
2014/11/21 16:05:00 19.56 -05.30
2014/01/31 13:55:00 02.00 31.10
2014/04/00 14:20:00 17.42 12.14
2014/07/25 15:30:00 35.25 05.90
2014/05/15 12:07:00 23.95 07.11
2014/07/29 17:34:00 44.00 17.43
2014/12/31 01:30:00 -14.00 09.43
2014/02/11 19:00:00 30.44 06.65
2014/03/20 18:00:00 -11.12 -22.05
2014/09/21 12:00:00 06.44 41.55
2014/03/19 11:44:00 16.41 -25.58
2014/04/06 04:53:00 36.11 07.21

Comment: Hi Mr. jackman, Thank you so much, the script that you suggested me has perfectly worked.